# How does using ? help against SQL injection in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my Rails application that I'm not really sure how it works.

```
@dogs = Dog.where(breed: search_breed).where(<<-SQL, search_color, search_name)
  color = ?
  AND name = ?
SQL
```

In the SQL portion, how is putting the search_color and search_name inside the SQL start and using ? inside the SQL different/better than this?

```
@dogs = Dog.where(breed: search_breed).where(<<-SQL)
 color = search_color
 AND name = search_name
SQL
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason to use raw SQL here. That code seems really confused and should be:

```
@dogs = Dog.where(
  breed: search_breed,
  color: search_color,
  name: search_name
)
```

If you're using `AND` that's how `where` works by default. That will take care of properly escaping everything for you

Injections occur when you make the mistake of doing:

```
Dog.where("breed = #{search_breed}") # WRONG!
```

Which you really **do not** want to ever do.

The safe alternative is this:

```
Dog.where("breed=?", search_breed)
```

In this case the database driver substitutes `?`, which is called a *placeholder value* with the properly escaped `search_breed` value. Properly escaped here means "avoids SQL injection problems".

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand why the placeholder is preferred over the alternative.

Comment: The alternative means your server gets cracked wide open by a tool like [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org). Failing to escape properly is the number one cause of security problems, hands down. If you're writing a JSON document you **must** escape for JSON, same for HTML or in a URL, otherwise things like XSS become a problem. Placeholder values *will* escape things properly, and they do so in a way that makes it obvious, so you can audit your code and see at a glance that everything is done correctly. This is not the case with string interpolation, you must carefully check each inlined value.

Answer (score 0):

Because without the placeholder, your query string is not escaped. If malicious user send drop table command to your db, its gone.

```
Client.where("first_name LIKE '%#{params[:first_name]}%'")
```

This is opened to sql injection. Any input from user is taken as is by your db.

```
'John'; DROP TABLE clients;--
```

Use placeholder to guard against injection.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I still don't understand what it means to "escape" and how using a placeholder helps?

Comment: To escape a code means the given code will not be executed. It will remain as string and not running as a code. You never want user being able to execute sql command directly from input ever. Using a placeholder and the given input will be escaped automatically by rails, you dont have to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

To build on previous answers, SQL injection can be very dangerous for a number of reasons. Injection attacks enable sneaky users to read or manipulate data in your database via the "OR 1.." statement.

Lets say you have an application in which there are many reports you can search. While certain reports should remain hidden to the public, you allow all users to access it like so in your show action:

**reports_controller.rb**

```
Reports.where("id = '#{params[:id]}'")
```

In this format the `'` never gets escaped. This allows a user to set attributes directly in your database with an OR 1 statement, a malicious user can generate a query something like:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE name = '' OR 1--'
```

Which would in fact return all records in the system to the user. Including ones that shouldn't be visible to them!

Another example would be bypassing the authentication system. If you validate login credentials something like so:

```
User.find_by("login = '#{params[:name]}' AND password = '#{params[:password]}'")
```

If the user inputs `' OR '1'='1` as the login value, and `' OR '2'>'1` as the password, the query will look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '' OR '1'='1' AND password = '' OR '2'>'1' LIMIT 1
```

Then not only would return the first user in the db, but it would also grant full access to the malicious user. 
But if you use this format:

```
User.find_by("login = ? AND password = ?", login_info, password_info).first
```

And what that will do is escape the `'` in the SQL statement so a user cannot exploit the query. You can use the short-hand hash form:

```
User.find_by(login: login_info, password: password_info)
```

and your query will still be protected.

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection   a very helpful section with more examples/details on this topic.